# Remove whitespace from left and right side of webpage (including header)

Tags: javascript, html, css, whitespace, margin

I'm building a website and noticed that when I stretch the webpage to full width, there is a weird whitespace that appears on both the left and right side (including the header and footer). I'm not quite sure how to fix it and none of the tutorials that I've read seemed to work either.

There is quite a bit of CSS so I've included below which parts I think could be causing the issue. If they seem fine, do let me know so that I can post other bits of code and debug those :)

```
html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    color: var(--primary-text-color);
    font-family: var(--font-base);
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    line-height: 1.6;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    word-break: break-word;
    background-color: var(--white-color);
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest using `html, body {  width: 100vw; }`, however, if you can please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Unfortunately I've already tried that and it didn't work. Also I'm editing the code of a preset theme so I'm not sure what code is causing the problem to include in a reproducible example. If it makes it easier, I can share a github link to the whole code

Comment: I seemed to have figured it out now! The CSS error was in another file in the theme

Comment: The code you've provided is not causing the issue. I just popped it into codepen and it worked fine. I would suggest either opening up the dev tools of whichever browser you're using and uncheckboxing styles on the HTML and body tags until it works, or copy paste the styles into codepen until it breaks. Make sure that the html tag, your body tag, your header tag, and your main tag all have width 100% though.

Comment: Yeah I found the issue in another file. Bit frustrating that the CSS is split into different files but I guess it makes debugging a bit easier

Comment: Cool. I'm glad there isn't an issue.

Comment: Not that it matters but if the issue is resolved without an answer you might consider updating the question with the name of your css library and providing a detailed answer of how you fixed it.